# Node.JS/MongoDB: document join solutions

Tags: node.js, mongodb, join

I have been trying to do a 3 document join with mongodb and am going around in circles (literally). I am attempting to do this leveraging async inside a loop to grab the additional documents and then build a custom json document that will be passed into my page. I am having limited success with this and am wonder if anyone has tried this or has some suggestions.

```
   MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/preInc", function(err, db) {
    if(err) { return console.dir(err); }
    var collection = db.collection('resource_Tbl');
    collection.find().toArray(function(err, items)
        {
        if(err) {
            return console.dir(err); }
        else {
            test = items;
            }
        for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++)
            {
            var temp = items[i]._id.toHexString();
            var name = items[i].name;
            console.dir(temp + "-|-" + name);
            Async.waterfall([
                    function getGeoAddress(callback)
                    {
                     console.dir(temp + "   " + name);
                     callback(null, 'unknown');
                    },
                ],
            function (err, results)
                {
                if (err)
                    {
                    console.log(err);
                    }
                else
                    {
                    }
                });
            }
        res.render('heatmap', { data: test, headerX:'preInc.org' });
        });
    });
});
```

the main problem I am running into now is that the loop works perfectly but the async does not start until after the loop has finished and only processes the last record (x times)

thank you in advance.

AEgir...

Comment: You can't join in MongoDB, if that's what you're asking. However you can do what you seem to be doing which is make a series of queries and combine the data. It would help if you post what you've tried and why it isn't working.

Comment: realized MongoDB does not support Joins several hours ago (too used to standard SQL and am trying something new). am cleaning up the code to post, thank you for the quick reply.